# Wiremock - Connection Refused - JUnit5

Tags: junit, junit5, wiremock

I have a stub that I can see under /__admin/ but when making any sort of rest calls nothing registers in either __admin/requests or __admin/requests/unmatched which I feel is strange. Is Wiremock failing to intercept the request?

Simplified code:

```
class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    void testStuff(){
        WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 9050); // Running in docker with custom port
        WireMock.reset();

        stubFor(
            get("/getStuff?include-archived=yes")
                .withPort(<myServicePort>)
                .willReturn(
                    aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withStatus(200)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error has been observed at the following site(s):     *__checkpoint ⇢
> Request to GET
> http://localhost:<myServicePort>/getStuff?include-archived=yes
> [DefaultWebClient]

...

> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver]
> : Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException:
> Connection refused: no further information:
> localhost/127.0.0.1:<myServicePort>; nested exception is
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
> refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:<myServicePort>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue, the port that I was trying to intercept wasn't open in the container thus why I got no entries in either __admin/requests or __admin/requests/unmatched